# How to add language support to Constants.h file?

Tags: iphone, ios, localization, constants

I have a `Constants.h` which has all strings which are used allover my app.

```
#define kGuideTitle @"Guide"
#define kSeatingTitle @"Seating"
#define kNotesTitle @"Notes"
#define kQuestionsTitle @"Questionnaire"
#define kTimelineTitle @"Timeline"
#define kMessagesTitle @"Messages"
```

Now I have a pressing need to localize that file to support multiple languages(5 languages).

I have got the translation for each language i need to support.

So I added lanugage support for `Constants.h` file from the inspector. And XCode created versions of `Constants.h` file for each language.

After that I edited the contents of the language specific files, like this.

```
Constants.h(Dutch)

#define kGuideTitle @"Leitfaden"
#define kSeatingTitle @"Sitzplan"
#define kNotesTitle @"Notizen"
#define kQuestionsTitle @"Fragebogen"
#define kTimelineTitle @"Zeitlinie"
#define kMessagesTitle @"Nachrichten"
```

But when I run the code in the simulator(Simulator language was set to Dutch), I am seeing only English version of the text all over the app. Why is it so?

Can any file be localized or only the localizable.strings file can be localized?

(I dont want to rework on shifting everything to localizable.strings file).

Can anyone please help?

Thanks very much.

Comment: that's dutch? looks more like deutsch (german)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it like that. A `#define` is replaced during the pre-processor stage before your code hits the compiler. i.e. only one set of your languages will ever get "compiled in". You will need to use localised strings.

Comment: No. If you want to localise you could either roll your own entire localisation technique (Note: You cannot do it at pre-processor stage. It has to be done at runtime.) or you can just use the technique Apple has given you.

Answer (score 0):

This is compiled code, using `.h` files this way will not allow you to change language at runtime.